# Firebase Many to Many Relations, how to Retrieve data

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

My database structure looks like this:

[image]

Now i want to retrieve only the products that belong to "menu1", and then Populate the ListView with them, i already have the class Products, and is there any way i can combine the query with FireBaseListAdapter, so first to get all products that belong to a menu ( eg "menu1", or "menu2" ), then use it with FireBaseListAdapter, can anyone help me with the query, how to achieve it?

p.s Its for an android app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use a `DatabaseReference` here since it extends the `Query` class.

```java
DatabaseRefernce mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                           .getReference("menus/menu1/listofproducts");
```

Or, if you already have a reference `mRef` to the root (restraunt-f08bd) that you want to use, you can use the following query

```java
Query menu1ProductsRef = mRef.child("menus/menu1/listofproducts");
```

And then set an `EventListener` on one of these.

In either of these queries you can add a `ChildEventListener` with the following code

```java
DatabaseReference productsRef = mRef.child("products");
menu1ProductsRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            productsRef.child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                //Add this product to your ListAdapter's ArrayList and notifyDataSetChanged()
                //Assuming you have a Product class with the necessary variables, getters and setters for these, and an empty constructor
                Product product = dataSnapshot.getValue(Product.class);
                productArrayList.add(product);
                productListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            //Add the corresponding code for this case
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //Add the corresponding code for this case
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            //Add the corresponding code for this case
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this returns a map(String,Bool), and thats not what i want. I was not so clear i guess in the first question, so i edited it, and gave more info what iam trying to do, hope u have it more clear now what i want and can help me.

Comment: if you have different products in each menu then it's better to include all the product information under the menu node itself, since otherwise you would have to make a different `Query` to either each of the products under menu1 or a query to all the products which would download more data than you need

Comment: Not all the time i will have different products in each menu, sometimes a product can be in 2 or more menus, and including all the information under the menu node itself, will duplicate my data. And i don't want either to download more data than i need, iam trying to figure out, when iam in menu1 for example, to download only products that belong to that menu, then when i go to menu2 download only products that belong to menu2 and so on

Comment: I've edited the answer. It adds products to the listAdapter if already created. But most databases of this kind do duplicate data in exchange for speed. This is what you get with a realtime database. I think these products don't really change in real time and so you don't need to use a realtime database for this.

Comment: Thanks, its working :), just change "Query productsRef" to "DatabaseReference productsRef" in order to use the .child() method!

Comment: @Pawnr can I get the full code? I not really understand Rohit code but this is exactly what I want, thank you.